# Expo-update and RN version issue

Tags: react-native, version, expo-updates

I have RN version of 0.64.2 and expo-update version of 0.5.5 and app is working fine. I have to update RN version to 0.64.4, but expo-update library 0.5.5 is giving error.- node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-android.gradle’ line: 13. Which version of expo-update library will be compaitable with RN 0.64.4

App is crashing. Getting foloowing error

`E/EmbeddedLoader: Could not read embedded manifest java.io.FileNotFoundException: app.manifest at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method) at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:874)`